# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ticket" is not found

Tags: python

I am making a ticket system with discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands 


from discord.ui import Button,button,View


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=discord.Intents.all())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("機器人開啟")


class CreateButton(View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        
    @button(label="Create Ticket",style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple,emoji="",custom_id="ticketopen")
    async def ticket(self,interaction: discord.Integration,button:Button):
        await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
        category:discord.CategoryChannel = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.categories,1118921939751288953)
        for ch in category.text_channels:
            if ch.topic == f"{interaction.user.id} DO NOT CHANGE THE TOPIC OF THIS CHANNEL!":
                await interaction.followup.send("你的票口正在開啟中{0}".format(ch.mention),ephemeral=True)
                return
            
        r1 : discord.Role = interaction.guild.get_role(1118922110690136226)
        overwrites = {
            interaction.guild.default_role:discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            r1: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_message = True,send_messages=True,manage_message=True),
            interaction.user:discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_message=True,send_messages=True),
            interaction.guild.me:discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_message=True,send_messages=True)
        }
        await category.create_text_channel(
            name=interaction.user,
            topic=f"{interaction.user.id} Do NOT CHANGE THE TOPIC OF THIS CHANNEL! ",
            overwrites=overwrites
        )
        await channel.send(
            embed=discord.Embed(
            
                title="新增窗口",
                description="不要聯繫工作人員",
                colour=0x7300ff
            )

        )
        await interaction.followup.send(
            embed=discord.Embed(
             description = "創建你的工單在{0}".format(channel.mention),
             color = discord.Color.white()
            )
        )

        @client.command(name="ticket")
        @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
        async def  ticket(ctx):
            await ctx.send(
                embed = discord.Embed(
                description="按下按鈕創建新的工單"
                ),
                View = CreateButton()
            )
```

What do I need to change?
The above code is copied from others

When I run this command in Discord, it raises this error in the terminal:

ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ticket" is not found